# both validators are showing simultanously when i leave "Email" input empty in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am implementing validations in angular 4 reactive forms. My form is like this

[image]

My validators code in app.component.html is here

```
    <label>Email
        <input type="text" formControlName="userEmail">
      </label>
      <div class="alert" 
   *ngIf="rForm.controls['userEmail'].hasError('required') && 
   rForm.controls['userEmail'].touched">Email is required</div>
      <div class="alert" 
  *ngIf="rForm.controls['userEmail'].hasError('email') && 
  rForm.controls['userEmail'].touched">Enter valid email</div>
```

Problem is this, when i left "Email field empty " so both validators is showing simultaneously like this

[image]

But i want that if user left "Email" field empty so only required validator should show and if user type wrong syntax so syntax validator should show
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **Else** with ngIf

```
 <label>Email
        <input type="text" formControlName="userEmail">
      </label>
      <div class="alert" 
   *ngIf="(rForm.controls['userEmail'].hasError('required') && 
   rForm.controls['userEmail'].touched); else formatError">Email is required</div>
<ng-template  #formatError >
      <div class="alert"
  *ngIf="rForm.controls['userEmail'].hasError('email') && 
  rForm.controls['userEmail'].touched">Enter valid email</div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I just gave you the idea. Can you provide me the codepen of your code so that i can make accurate adjustments to it.

Comment: sorry i have committed a mistake my self. any way i corrected it. your code worked for me thanks  :)

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
<div class="alert" 
   *ngIf="rForm.controls['userEmail'].hasError('required') && 
   rForm.controls['userEmail'].touched">Email is required</div>
<div class="alert" 
      *ngIf="!rForm.controls['userEmail'].hasError('required') && rForm.controls['userEmail'].hasError('email') && 
      rForm.controls['userEmail'].touched">Enter valid email</div>
```

Comment: by doing this , if user left the field empty or if user type wrong syntax in both cases this will show a same validator which is  "Enter valid Email" which is not i want. i want separate validators. if user left empty field so it should show "Email is required" and if user type wrong email it should show "Enter valid email"

Comment: @FahadSubzwari are you sure please recheck the condition in my answer

Comment: i have updated my ans with full code to avoid misunderstanding that you need only one div

Comment: by your solution when i left field empty so it is showing right validator that "email is required" but after that when i type wrong email syntax so it is showing "enter valid email" and is not disappearing even when i retype right syntax email.